# Contour Plot using NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I want to make a contour plot of the function $S$ using the following code taking $x$-asis along the horizontal and $y$-axis along vertical.

```
lam = 5.0;
gma = 0.5;
zeta = 2.0;
a = 0.5;
b = 2.0;
(*x=0.4;*)
t = 0.2;
Q0 = 1.0;
alp = 0.5;
F = Q0*Exp[-alp*t];
h = 1.0 - (a*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]);
sys1 = {s''[
     y] == (lam/2.0)^2.0*(Sinh[
        4.0*s[y]]/(1.0 + 4.0*gma*Sinh[2.0*s[y]]*Sinh[2.0*s[y]]))};
iv1 = {s[-h] == zeta, s[h] == zeta};
sol[x_] := NDSolve[Join[sys1, iv1], s, {y, -1, 1}]
ContourPlot[Evaluate[s[y] /. sol], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: I'm encouraging you to focus on making `NDSolve` return anything at all. You need to take care about passing `x` from `sol[x_]` inside `h`. Since you defined `sol` as a function you need to use it as such `... /. sol` does not make sense in this context. Once you have basic issues solved it should be easy to use it for a `ContourPlot`

Comment: Could you kindly let me know what exactly changes need to be made in the above code to get a contour plot of s?

Comment: s is a function of a single variable? If so, what do you mean by contour plot?

Comment: Yes. I agree with you that s is a function of single variable. But the boundary conditions depend on h which implies boundary conditions depends on x. So we must have a contour which I want to plot.

Comment: @BiswajitMallick. Surely you meant a `ContourPlot` like that?,because it shows nothing interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"](*Clears all constans*)

lam = 5.0;
gma = 0.5;
zeta = 2.0;
a = 0.5;
b = 2.0;(*x = 0.4*)
t = 0.2;
Q0 = 1.0;
alp = 0.5;
F = Q0*Exp[-alp*t];
h = 1.0 - (a*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]);

sys1 = {s''[y] == (lam/2.0)^2.0*(Sinh[4.0*s[y]]/(1.0 + 4.0*gma*Sinh[2.0*s[y]]*Sinh[2.0*s[y]]))};

iv1 = {s[-h] == zeta, s[h] == zeta};

sol[x_] := NDSolve[Join[sys1, iv1], s, {y, -1, 1}]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[s[y] /. sol[x], {x, 0, 1, 1/10}]], {y, 0, 1}, 
PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]

ListPlot3D[Partition[Flatten[Table[
Evaluate[Table[{x, y, (s[y] /. sol[x])[[1]]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/20}]], {y, 0, 1,1/20}]], 3]]

ListContourPlot[Partition[Flatten[Table[
Evaluate[Table[{x, y, (s[y] /. sol[x])[[1]]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/30}]], {y, 0, 1,1/30}]], 3], PlotLegends -> Automatic,FrameLabel -> {X, Y}]
```

[image]

`I'm edited in yours actual code.`

Comment: Thank you so much. Thank you for your kind help.